# Was offered a PhD position, I accepted it but no replies afterwards from the potential supervisors

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions, advisor, interview, austria

I gave an interview for a Phd position and I was offered the position within a day of the interview. I accepted the offer withing two days (before the deadline) and sent an email stating my acceptance of the offer to the supervisor who interviewed me. No acknowledgement was given  and thereafter I have not received any further emails from their side. I sent another email to follow up and ask if they received my first email, but still no replies. It is now been 2 weeks since they last emailed me. Should I keep waiting, or send another email or just move on and apply for other positions.

I tried all emails I could find to contact them. It is not an email delivery problem, since I corresponded with them using the same email many times before the interview took place and I am receiving emails from other people without any problem.

Edit : Now I have another PhD offer and have a deadline to acfept and reject. Still no replies from the first offer. It is almost been a month now.

What would be the best way to go ahead in this situation? I don't want to be dishonest by accepting both offers and but I also don't want to lose both in case the first offer doesn't work out.
The first offer was not an official one. The email read ' We would like to offer you in the position.'

Comment: Try again.  There is a crisis.  People are more busy than usual, and usual is pretty busy.

Comment: Can you find a phone number of the professor or some secretary related to his chair? But even if you find a number, they might be in their home office and might not answer the phone.

Comment: How long has it been since the actual deadline for acceptance?

Comment: After the offer, I was given 3 days to accept. I accepted on the second day. It is been 12 days since the deadline.

Comment: I did try a phone number @usr1234567 but no one picked up. Must be the same reason you pointed out.

Comment: Thanks,  @Anonymous Physicist.

Comment: Ordinarily, I'd say not to worry, but given the current situation I can understand being concerned. Have you contacted the department the professor is a member of? They might be able to respond on the professor's behalf.

Comment: How many different people have you tried to contact?

Comment: By "PhD position" do you mean a job for people who hold PhDs or for a PhD studentship? What country? | Also, why the [thesis] tag?

Comment: @Bryan Krause, I tried to contact two people who interviewed me.

Comment: @Worriedandwaiting Can you try contacting some administrative staff? Who did you receive the offer from? Was it a formal (like a legal contract) or informal offer ("we'd love to have you")?

Comment: @Azor ahai , A Phd studentship. A PhD thesis, at least that's what I meant from the tag . The position is in Austria.

Comment: @Bryan krause, the offer was not an official one. The email read 'We would like to offer you this position.' I did try contacting HR. I guess everything is closed due to the pandemic.

Comment: @Bryan Krause, Done.

Comment: How did it go? tell us!

Comment: Hi @EarlGrey , the supervisor did reply after 45 days. I was worried until then. They did not explain or give any reason for the delay in replying. Towards the end, I messaged the supervisor asking them to confirm their offer or I stated that it was in my best interest to accept the other offer. They reconfirmed their offer. So it ended well.

Comment: Corona crazy time! Good luck with your research!

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you have any reason to worry. Under the current strain and disruption of the pandemic people aren't able to do the things they would normally do. A couple of weeks isn't very long after a deadline as there are probably quite a few administrative tasks that seem to them to be more important to them than reassuring students. The professor in question might have additional issues preventing them from responding in a timely manner (or at all, if they are ill or caring for a family member).

Assume that all is well. You've done what was required of you.

Don't keep hammering, though, as it just makes their workload worse.

On the other hand, you are due an acknowledgement that all is well. A once-a-week email is probably appropriate until you get confirmation.

Note that normal phone numbers aren't being answered at some places. Buildings are locked and people are forbidden to enter, even to retrieve personal effects.

---

You could, however, keep abreast of any news pertaining to that university by doing web searches. There is a lot of disruption and universities are planning how to finish out this year and finding ways to be flexible for next. Bad things are happening. They could continue to happen.

Comment: Thanks a lot Buffy. I will just wait for another week before sending my third email.

Comment: I have an opportunity to interview for a new PhD position now. Not sure how to explain my situation to them. Still no replies from the first PhD offer. Should i go for the interview? Or would it be dishonest to attend the interview?